# Only hear music of the films on headset

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I'm having difficulty watching many new films using my headset. For example `A.Film.2017.1080p.WEB-DL.X264.AC3-EVO.mkv`.
I can hear the music but the conversations sound like a hardly noticable humming noise.
I don't have this problem with old films. So I guess is something to do with 5.1 audio records.

```
sudo aplay -l 
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: SoundCard [Xonar SoundCard], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: SoundCard [Xonar SoundCard], device 1: USB Audio [USB Audio #1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: SoundCard [Xonar SoundCard], device 2: USB Audio [USB Audio #2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: SoundCard [Xonar SoundCard], device 3: USB Audio [USB Audio #3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

In sound settings, my output device is set to `Speakers Xonar Sound Card` and Configuration is `Analog 5.1  Output`. I can not hear any sound when I choose other options.

Appreciate your hints to resolve this.

Comment: Since you're using a headset I think the configuration on your output should be 2 channel stereo, then it should mix down the 5.1 so it can be heard through your headset.

Comment: right, but I get no voice when I choose `2.1` in sound configuration.

Comment: 2.1 still suggests an additional sub-woofer is expected on top of the two speakers, is there just a stereo option?